Timing marks not lining up on 2.2 dohc Saturn
2001 Saturn 2.2 dual overhead cam 16 valve timing marks not lining up right the cam on the exhaust side is not at the 45° angle it needs to be it's more or less like the 10:00 position need to find out how to get it to line up correctly before I put all the new chain on if you can help me please and appreciate it and yes it's TDC correctly it's just the one cam is not lining up help please

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Thanks for having me

This video may be of help to you.

It helps some as for telling where the marks have to be but the cam on the exhaust side is way off but the others are perfectly in place  so how do I line that cam or do I need to pull the heads and re do the valves

I don't know what you mean by "way off", but realistically you just need to move the cam into position, but do it easily. There will be some resistance as cam lobes push on the valve springs. Use the flats on the cam which is not in position to get it into position. If one cam is where it should be, lock it into position. If the crank is where it needs to be, don't touch it.
I take it when you say the exhaust cam needs to be "at 45° angle" but is at 10:00 position, it needs to come clockwise about 85-90°? Since this is the rotation of the engine, this should not pose any problems as far as interference (valve to piston) as long as you don't move the crankshaft. Rotate the exhaust cam into position, then lock it down so it doesn't move (as suggested in the video). Once it is in position, follow the video and complete the job.
For Reference: Saturn 2.2L Ecotec video

I thank you very much this is the first time I had this issue thanks for your response and help may God bless you once again thanks
